# awsebcli ImportError no module named 'data_poller' python 3.4.3

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, conda

I am trying to deploy a website using Elastic Beanstalk. In the process, I am trying to set up awsebcli, the command line interface for elastic beanstalk. I have created a virtual environment with python 3.4.3 using conda and then pip install awsebcli. After installation I call:

```
eb --version
```

And get an import error:

```
ImportError: No Module named 'data_poller'
```

I have found the data_poller.py file and the DataPoller class in the file. I do not know why this is not importing and preventing eb from working. I have used both MacOS 10.11 and Ubuntu 16.10 with the same results. How do I fix the import error and get elastic beanstalk cli to work?

Answer (score 4):

Something seems to be wrong with the latest version.  I just installed it on a clean machine and got the same error.  If I force it back to the prior version I can do the eb --version without error now.

pip install awsebcli==3.8.8 --force-reinstall

Comment: Yes worked for me too, though needed make sure I used "--user" as that ws the option I used (per AWS docs on how to install awsebcli)